# What is the stable DNS name of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Given an EC2 instance spun up in AWS, does AWS provide a stable, predictable, DNS name that resolves to both the public IPv4 and public IPv6 addresses of that instance?

If so, where can I find this name, and how do I turn this name on?

Stable means that name will not change if the instance is stopped. This rules out the classic IPv4 DNS names that contained the randomly assigned IPv4 address.

Public means not the IPv4 RFC1918 address assigned to the internal interface.

Route 53 exists, and I am aware that I can deploy Route 53 entries alongside an instance and have done so in the past, however I am talking about a DNS name provided by AWS under their own domain that does not require extra configuration over and above deploying an instance with parameters correctly set.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. Give the instance an elastic IP and a DNS record pointing to that if you want this. [Cattle, not pets.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets)

Comment: @ceejayoz Elastic IP is IPv4 only, so alas doesn't answer the question in this case.

Comment: "elastic network interfaces retain their IPv6 addresses throughout their lifetime" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/ipv6-on-aws/amazon-vpc-internet-access.html